# Need a query to find a string in address column

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I want to select first 4 letters of the address string ignoring the numbers or P.O. box.

For example, I have a database column "address" in "customers" table.

```
51 church st
```

In a query, I only want "chur" ignoring the numbers.  It can be any number.  I am not interested in number.  Also, I don't want this for just one record.  I want this to happen for every record 
So for example I have these records:

```
51 church st
6178 fookeral ave
597537 state ct
```

In my 1 query i want results look like this

```
Chur
Fook
Stat
```

How can I get this in one query?

Answer (score 1):

The [`CHARINDEX`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) function lets you search for a string within another string.  Use this to find the location of the space character, then take the 4 following characters.

Here's an example:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING([Address], CHARINDEX(' ', [Address]) + 1, 4)
FROM [Your_Table]
```

Comment: I am using Toad and CHARINDEX function is not working in toad please give me a alternative query that will work in Toad.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `CHARINDEX`you could use [PATINDEX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) and have it match any character in the `a-z`range:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(address, PATINDEX('%[a-z]%', address), 4) AS FirstFour
FROM customers
```

This would give the correct result if you have any address like `51 32 church st`, that is with a number followed by a space followed by another number.

This solution assumes you use Microsoft SQL Server.

**Edit: added a solution for Oracle (tested with 11g R2).**

In Oracle you can use regular expressions and the [REGEXP_SUBSTR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm) function like this:

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_SUBSTR("Address",'[[:alpha:]]{4}') "FourChars",
  INITCAP(REGEXP_SUBSTR("Address",'[[:alpha:]]{4}')) "FourCharsInitCap"
FROM customers
```

This returns:

```
FOURCHARS   FOURCHARSINITCAP
chur        Chur
fook        Fook
stat        Stat
```

Comment: I am using Toad and PATINDEX function is not working in toad please give me a alternative query that will work in Toad.

Comment: @user2990687 Isn't Toad just a front end query tool? What back end database are you using?

Comment: Back end database is Oracle.

Comment: @user2990687 I've updated my answer to include a solution for Oracle that should work.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked for most of it but still there's a problem for 2 addresses. So lets say if the address is PO BOX 9999; your query returns BOX. what I want is PO . Space is also count as character. Another address is 9838 20th st. The query above doesn't give me any value. what I want is to return 20t. Any suggestions for these 2 scenario.